# MPEG-DASH Encoder error

Tags: mpeg-dash

I have installed x264, gpac revision 3744, ffmpeg and DashEncoder on ubuntu 10.04 (on vwware) successfully but when I run DashEncoder with below config file I received this error:

current encoder x264
YES
terminate called after throwing an instance of ‘std::logic_error’
what(): basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
Aborted(core dumped)

(note: I can produce mpd files using MP4Box directly but DASH Encoder doesn't work. Also I test it with newer revision of gpac)

Please help me

thanks

```
#========================================
# Config File for DASH Encoder
#========================================

#========================================
# General Options
#========================================

dest-directory : /home/pardis/Downloads/DASHEncoder-master/out

video-encoder : x264
audio-encoder : ffmpegAAC
multiplexer : mp4box

#store-psnr
#sql-host : localhost
#sql-user : root
#sql-pw :
#sql-database : dash

add-non-segmented

use-ffmpeg-pipe
ffmpeg-opt : -f rawvideo
#input-res : 384×208
#input-res : 352×288
input-res : 320×240
#========================================
# x264 Options
#========================================

bitrate : 300

#bitrate : 250@480×360|500@480×360|1000
#bitrate : 200|400|600|1000
statistics : stat.temp
gop : 48
scenecut : 0
profile : baseline
preset : slow
input : /home/pardis/sample.m4v
#input : /home/stefan/foreman_cif.y4m
#input : /home/stefan/kingkong.mp4
#input : /media/Volume/MI200802010028-video_newsroom_hd_1080_p29_97-channelSelectionT0C0_T0C1.mp4
passes : 1
const-filesize : 0

#Additional Options for Encoding

#pass1 : –frames 500 –fps 29.970029
pass1 : –verbose –fps 24
pass2 : –verbose –psnr

#========================================
# FFMPEG AAC Options
#========================================

# [channels, samplerate, bitrate]
#audio-quality : 2,44100,48|2,44000,128
#audio-quality : 2,44100,48
#audio-quality :

#audio-input : /home/stefan/sintel_trailer-audio.flac
#audio-codec : libfaac

#========================================
# MP4Box Options
#========================================

#AV Muxing
#mux-combi : 300@48|600@128
#mux-combi :

fragment-size : 200
segment-size : 200
rap-aligned
segment-name : test
folder-prefix : test

#========================================
# MPD Options
#========================================
mpd-name : test.mpd
url-root : http: //localhost:8080/test/
#set-base-url
mpdActStandardPostfix : _actVersion.mpd
duration : 5S
#transform-mpd
minBufferTime : 2.0S
segDuration : 1
#========================================
# Other Options
#========================================
```

Comment: Hi MSH, I see that you have solved the problem yourself. Could you perhaps answer your own question so that other people can benefit from it? As you can see, @user3805122 is having the same problem and is looking for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that DASHEncoder assumes you want to encode a video and an audio file concurrently. So if you just want to encode a video file you should comment some parts of DASHEncoder code that relates to processing audio files.